# Hey, I have this php code to call python file but it gives an error when I run the php code on browser..:

Tags: php, python

php code:

```
<?php
   exec("C:/Python27/python qwer.py 2>&1", $output);
   print_r($output);
?>
```

Python code:

```
f = open('myfile.txt','w')
f.write('hi there\n')
```

Error:

```
Array ( [0] => C:/Python27/python: can't open file 'qwer.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give the full path for qwer.py like below

```
<?php
   exec("C:/Python27/python c:/scripts/qwer.py 2>&1", $output);
   print_r($output);
?>
```

Comment: it is still giving error:Array ( [0] => C:/Python27/python: can't open file 'c:/scripts/qwer.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory )

Comment: @abcdxx `c:/scripts/qwer.py` was just an example, use the full path to the file `qwer.py` according to your system.

Comment: i wrote:exec("C:/Python27/python C:/xampp/htdocs/qwer.py 2>&1", $output);
print_r($output);  but it is not creating any myfile.txt still although not giving any error now

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary it is still not creating any myfile.txt although it is not giving any error now

Comment: @abcdxx It must be creating `'myfile.txt'`, look at the correct location. But the file is going to be empty as you didn't flush the data from buffer to the file. Add a `f.close()` line after `f.write` line to do that.

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary No,I looked into my current directory where qwer.py is stored myfile.txt is not created there even if I use f.close().. will u pls help me wid dat??

Comment: Do one thing, give full path for myfile.txt also where you want to save it and see if it works. or check in C:/Python27/ folder. that file may be there.. To avoid such confusion, prefer to provide full path for all file related functionalities.

Comment: yeah.. thanks @Abani I found myfile.txt it was saved in other folder..:)